# SwiftUI MenuButton with more than 10 Items

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI MenuButton that works great with 10 or fewer items:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MenuButton("My Button") {
            Button("A") { }
            Button("B") { }
            Button("C") { }
            Button("D") { }
            Button("E") { }
            Button("F") { }
            Button("G") { }
            Button("H") { }
            Button("I") { }
            Button("J") { }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when adding an 11th item, it won't compile because SwiftUI limits groups to size 10. With a normal group (like a `VStack`) I would just wrap some of the items in a `Group` or `Section`, but that messes up the visuals for `MenuButton`.

Wrapping the first 5 elements in a `Group`:

[image: Wrapped in a group]

Wrapping the first 5 elements in a `Section`:

[image: Wrapped in a section]

Wrapping the first 5 elements in a `VStack` (the spacing is fine, but the entire group is selectable together):

[image: Wrapped in a vstack]

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution - you can keep array of items to configure each menu item button. Tested with Xcode 11.4.

[image: demo]

```
struct TestLongMenuButton: View {
    let actions = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L"]

    var body: some View {
        MenuButton("My Button") {
            ForEach(actions, id: \.self) { action in
                Button(action) { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Asperi's solution is solid. Here's a version that allows for distinct actions for each item with relative compile safety (as long as each label can be distinct).

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    enum Item: String, CaseIterable {
        case a = "Label A"
        case b = "Label B"

        func performAction() -> Void {
            switch self {
            case .a:
                print("Doing a")
            case .b:
                print("Doing b")
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        MenuButton("My Button") {
            ForEach(Item.allCases, id: \.self) { key in
                Button(key.rawValue, action: key.performAction)
            }
        }
    }
}
```